# How to merge files in correct order using command prompt

Tags: batch-file, cmd, merge, concatenation, command-prompt

I have a folder with video segments from a mpeg-dash video.
there is an "init.mp4" file along with 275 segments, i.e. "seg-1.m4s", "seg-2.m4s" and so on. I want to merge them in a single file.
I am using the following command in cmd:
`copy /b init.mp4 + seg-*.m4s source.mp4`
The above code is merging the files in wrong order. [see the merge order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7I7n.jpg)

How do I merge the files in the correct order like, 1,2,3...9,10,11..19,20...

*Also note that I have tried merging them one by one using a loop. but that is way slower compared to the above code*

Comment: The core problem is that cmd.exe is sorting them as character strings. Is there any way you could get all files named with a three (3) digit value? seg-001.mp4, seg-020.mp4, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am actually using a python script to download these segments. So i can easily save them with whatever name I want. I think this solves my problem. thanks again

Comment: If you're already using a Python script, why not use the same script to append each segment to the main file right from the source? That would save having to create an additional script to do the merge.

Comment: I found the command line option to be faster. Is there any way to merge the files faster using python only?

Comment: p.s. I am not creating a separate batch script to merge. I am calling the `os.system( )` function in python

Comment: One way to do it in Python is to not create the segment files at all, but just append all of the data in turn to a single file. It takes just as long to create a segment file as it does to append to an existing file, therefore it would save you however long it takes to combine all the files.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I am downloading 25 segments at a time using multiprocessing. I think its not possible to merge files as I download them because multiprocessing does not download the segments in order. However if its possible, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need to rename files:

```bat
 1 -  9 to 001 - 009:
10 - 99 to 010 - 099:
```

**in cmd:**

```bat
for /l %l in (1 1 9) do @ren seg-%l.m4s seg-00%l.m4s
for /l %l in (10 1 99) do @ren seg-%l.m4s seg-0%l.m4s
```

**and in batch file:**

```bat
for /l %%l in (1 1 9) do ren seg-%%l.m4s seg-00%%l.m4s
for /l %%l in (10 1 99) do ren seg-%%l.m4s seg-0%%l.m4s
```

**After this, run your code:**

```bat
copy /b init.mp4 + seg-*.m4s source.mp4
```

Comment: @phclv- nOp- need put files in right order first, then merge files.

Comment: no. he doesn't need to rename the files. And you only add the merge part after my comment

Answer (score 2):

A very simple pure Batch-file solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Sort file names in numerical order
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=-." %%a in ('dir /B *.m4s') do (
   set /A "num=1000+%%b"
   set "file[!num!]=%%a-%%b.m4s"
)

rem Create the ordered list
set "files=init.mp4"
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set file[') do set "files=!files! + %%a"

rem Do it
copy /B %files% source.mp4
```

Comment: Problem is, if there are enough files, you'll reach the 8k command line length limit.

Comment: after running this batch script i got source.mp4 of size 1kb

Comment: @DodgyCodeException: With 3 digits, each `+ seg-123.m4s` file name takes 14 chars, so this method may manage a max of 8192/14 = 585 files. The OP specified 275 files, so...

Comment: Good point. But why is the OP getting a resulting file size of only 1 KB? Maybe your first `for /f` should use a command rather than a file spec?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done fairly easily. Put this code in a file named `mp4match.ps1`. The key to this code that the sorting is done on the numeric value in the filename. It is extracted by a `regex`.

```
$segments = Get-ChildItem -File -Filter 'seg-*.mps' |
    Sort-Object @{Expression={([int]([regex]::match($_.Name, 'seg\-(\d*).mps')).Groups[1].Value)}} |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Name }

'init.mp4 ' + $segments -join ' '
```

Then, use this batch file to run it. When the `COPY` command looks correct, remove the `ECHO` at the beginning of the line.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%f IN ('powershell -NoProfile -File .\mp4match.ps1') DO (
    SET "FILE_LIST=%%f"
)
IF EXIST ".\source.mp4" (DEL ".\source.mp4")
COPY /Y %FILE_LIST% source.mp4
```